How to show cart page coupon error messages different location
I need to show, WooCommerce Error message on different location
This is my cart page (screenshot):

I have search hook function for this, but I didn't get it.
How can I change the location of the displayed coupon error notice on cart page? Is there any hook for that?

There are no hooks for that, the only way should be to intercept the coupon event check that display this error notice, and with a bit of JavaScript, you could try to hide the displayed message, and clone it to be displayed in the desired location.

Okay...I will try

woocommerce_add_notice is what adds the error. So use it to filter and prevet showing error.  Then in your coupon form you can use js to add div where to show your error and use js events like applied_coupon (cart page) , applied_coupon_in_checkout (checkout page) to trigger your message.
